# How to use the "Bootstrap.dat" file with bitcoin-qt?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bootstrap.dat

I have searched around, and nothing I find works for me.
Downloaded the approx. 10 GB Bootstrap.dat file. Now stuck on trying to link it with Bitcoin-QT.

Tried the following command in the console box in the bitcoin-qt app:

```
bitcon-qt -loadblock=/path/to/bootstrap.dat
```

Also tried copying the file into the AppData/Roaming/Bitcoin file... Still no luck.

I'm running Windows 7, anyone have step by step instructions on how to set this up?

Comment: Your question may be best addressed to the [original post on the BitcoinTalk forum](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=117982.0).

Comment: it did help me thanks! Im running bitcoin-qt 0.8.5 on a mac os10.9 , and i downloaded the bootstrap.dat file, dumped it on /application support/bitcoin/ and the client found it and started importing blocks from disk. all G! cheers

Comment: Any one know how to do this running windows 8

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 10):

Okay, it appears after much trial and error, I figured out that you put the `bootstrap.dat` file in the `AppData/Roaming/Bitcoin` or `~/.bitcoin` folder. You can leave everything else in that folder untouched, just add the `bootstrap.dat` file in the Bitcoin folder.

I left `bootstrap.dat` in there, and finally Bitcoin-QT found it, and on the bottom it states "Importing blocks from disk..." I'm currently at 80 weeks behind on the update, compared to 240+.

I was reading crap about using the `-loadblock` command and extracting/unzipping the `.dat` file.... well this wasn't needed.  At least it isn't needed on the current version of QT, which I believe is .8.0.5

Comment: It didn't work for me. Just left in the same directory of wallet.dat and it did not work. This directory should be empty? Without any block previously downloaded?

Comment: On Linux, I made sure the folder was empty when I put bootstrap.dat there. Also, I used a different folder, so I started bitcoin-qt with bitcoin-qt -datadir=/media/downloads/bitcoin . Probably it saved the datadir in its config file, I will check that later.

Answer (score 7):

I tried putting blockfile in .bitcoin directory and starting ./bitcoind
but doesn't works. By the way, this method works best for me.

```
./bitcoind -loadblock=~/.bitcoin/bootstrap.dat
```

You need to use loadbloack syntax with the ./bitcoind .